# Why are there four fields in my sublime snippet when I only have three fields defined?

Tags: sublimetext3

I have the following snippet:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
### ${1:title}
#### ${2:sub title}
${3:summary}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>qnote</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

it runs fine except when I invoke it sublime is looking for 4 tab fields instead of three, so when I'm done filling in the summary I have to hit tab again to fill the fourth field. Why is this happening and how do I change the behavior so there are only three tab fields? Thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default, snippets contain an extra hidden "field" at the end, so that you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to move the cursor to after the end of the snippet, regardless of where the last field is defined in the snippet.

Therefore, you probably want to change your snippet to remove the `${3:summary}`, so that it will look like this:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
### ${1:title}
#### ${2:sub title}
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>qnote</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <!-- <scope>source.python</scope> -->
</snippet>
```

and it will behave the way you desire.